# Why does readlines() include a \n character in my text file if it doesn't exist?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to read a file and collect every character which includes the following: "\n" "\t" " "

My text file contains the following:

```
aaabbcddd
```

I intentionally left out \n, so python should stop reading at d.

The code is as follows:

```
fname  = "files.txt"
content = []
with open(fname) as f:
    for each_line in f:
        for each_character in each_line:
            content.append(each_character)


print(content)
```

My output for content is:

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', '\n']
```

It is fine if '\n' is stored in my list if it was intentionally inserted; however, in this instance, I did not put '\n'.

What went wrong?

Comment: It's because your text editor added a \n to the last line in your file. Run `xxd files.txt` so you can see a hex view of what's inside that file. Run `echo -n aaabbcddd > files.txt` to create a file without a newline at the end and try again.

Comment: You must have a newline in the file. I can't reproduce your problem using your script.

Comment: Thank you @nos, what you've explained is exactly what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read a line.

A line is terminated by a newline character.  I am pretty sure that your text editor inserts that at the end of what you typed.

Try adding a simple trace of what you get on input:

```
for each_line in f:
    print(len(each_line), "|", each_line, "|")
```

My output:

```
10 | aaabbcddd
 |
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', '\n']
```

Even though I did *not* add a return character to the file, and it has only a single line, the editor (vi) assumes it.  The input string has 9 letters and the newline.

Comment: Note that this is a reasonable thing for a text editor to do. The official POSIX [definition of a text file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_file#Unix_text_files) is a file organized into zero or more lines, where a "line" is a sequence of non-newline characters followed by a terminating newlines. This means that, by POSIX standards, a text file *must* either be empty or end in a newline; any text file without a newline at the end of its final logical line is technically not POSIX compliant. It's trivially easy to verify; on a UNIX-like system, just run `xxd -g1 myfile`, and you'll see it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your text file does not have a newline after this string? I've tried running your code as is, and it does not include the '\n' in the array. This is what is outputted:

`['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd']`

Sometimes a newline could be inserted accidentally in the text file and it doesn't hurt to double check.

Comment: This appears to be the case. I've created my text file using Vim, I tried creating the file again using @nos's command and the line doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the text editor saves automatically a newline character?